# show Progress Dialog in OnLocationChanged

Tags: android, progressdialog

I know there are thousands of questions like this. But I can't find an explanation to mine.

I use the onLocationChanged method to update the user's location on a mapView. Everything's fine; I display a ProgressDialog in the onCreate method and dismiss it at the end of OnlocationChanged and it works.

The problem is when I create and show a Progress Dialog inside the onLocationChanged method. Somehow it doesn't work. I think it's because the method runs on a different thread.

But my question is, if the onLocationChanged method runs on a different thread, why does it let me to dismiss the dialog but not create a new one?

Here's part of my class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tiendas);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setSatellite(false);

    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(StoresActivity.this, "", 
    "Getting your location", true, true);


 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             /////if i show or initialize the dialog here, doesn't work!

             updateMap(location)  // this function calls asynctask 
                                                 //  for an HTTPrequest
     dialog.dismiss();


        }
```

}

**That code works and dismisses the dialog correctly, but if I declare or show the dialog inside the onLocationChanged method, it never displays. Anybody?
Why does it dismiss it but can't show it?**

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `Context` of `LocationListener` class in `ProgressDialog`.

Comment: OK. Pass StoresActivity.this context in AsyncTask.

Answer (score -1):

Check this code its working fine for me

public class LocationFinderActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

```
LocationManager locationManager = null; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_finder);

    Log.i("inside","oncreate");
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0,this);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_location_finder, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Log.i("inside","onlocationchange");
    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LocationFinderActivity.this, "", 
            "Getting your location", true, true);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}